# Finding combinations as per name

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a function in JavaScript that given a string will return an array of all combinations of the name for eg.

```
 Name As per ITD - Potter Harry James 
                   Potter Harry 
                   Harry Potter
                   Harry James Potter
```

The below code also gives combination but in this way :

```
 Name As per ITD - Potter Harry 
                   Potter James 
                   Potter
                   Potter Harry James 
                   Harry James 
                   Harry 
                   James
```

**Code :**

```js
var PanName = "Harry James Potter";
var ret = PanName.split(" ").reduce(function(ret, el, i, arr) {
  var n = arr.slice(++i);
  [2, 3].forEach(function(c) {
    ret = ret.concat(n.map(function(_, i) {
      return [el].concat(n.slice(i)).slice(0, c).join(' ');
    }));
  });
  if (i === arr.length - 1) ret.pop();
  return ret;
}, []);
var arr = ret.toString().split(",");
arr = arr.map(function(el) {
  return el.trim();
});

arr = arr.filter(function(item, index, inputArray) {
  return inputArray.indexOf(item) == index;
});
var i;
var text1 = "";
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  text1 += arr[i] + "<br>";
}
$('#displayCombinationNames').html(text1);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="displayCombinationNames"></p>
```

Can anyone please help me in getting the output below:

**Expected Output :**

```
Name As per ITD - Potter Harry James 
                  Potter Harry 
                  Harry Potter
                  Harry James Potter
```

Comment: Is it possible, that there could be more than one middle names?

Comment: @Teemu yes it is possible

Comment: You asked for _"all combinations of the name"_ but your example doesn't show all combinations. What about "Harry James" as well as the other combinations? Do you really want all combinations, or just a specific subset?

Comment: You are right, I just need specific combinations as per the examples above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by treating names with only first and last name separately to longer cases. For the first case, the result is simply an array of `first last` and `last first`. For the latter case, the result includes those values but also with the middle names following the first:

```js
var PanName = "Harry James Potter";
var arr = PanName.split(' ');
var ret;

if (arr.length == 2) {
  ret = [arr.join(' '), arr.reverse().join(' ')];
} else {
  ret = [arr.join(' ')];
  first = arr.shift();
  last = arr.pop();
  ret.push([first, last].join(' '), [last, first].join(' '));
  ret.push([last, first, arr].join(' '));
}
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: can you help me, what if name contains 4 words  `var PanName = "Potter Harry James Lilly";`

Comment: @Kmayur7777 what is your expected output? Note that for that data there would need to be some indication that the last name was actually the first value...